# Common Feature between Scala Trait ,Java Interface and Java Class

Tags: java, scala, interface, traits

I am little confused about what the common feature does **Scala trait and Java Interface** have? Also what is common feature present in **Scala trait and Java Class** have but not present in **Java Interface** ?

Answer (score 0):

"what the common feature does Scala trait and Java Interface have?"

Both Java interfaces and Scala traits can define zero or more abstract members (fields, methods) that can be used by several classes. Importantly, in Java a class can "implement" many interfaces, and in Scala a class can mixin many traits. Instances of these classes also count as instances of the interface/trait in the type system. So interfaces/traits provide some of the benefits of multiple inheritance (with restrictions and limitations in each case) that you can't recreate with only the built in full single inheritance.

"what is common feature present in Scala trait and Java Class have but not present in Java Interface ?"

Both traits and Java classes can define implementions of members, while interfaces can only declare members but not give them implementation bodies. For instance the Scala trait:

```
object Energy
class Food
trait Eats {
   def eat(f: Food) = Energy
}
```

Could be mixed into both Cat and Dog abstracting the logic into the trait, while in a Java interface the method can be defined but each class will have to duplicate the implementation logic.

Answer (score 0):

Starting Java 8, you can define "default methods" on interface (as well as static methods), so that java interface and scala trait become equivalent.